# Google Pay card 3DS handling on Android

Tags: android, google-pay

Hi does anyone know is Google Pay SDK handles 3DS inside SDK and nothing additional needs to be done, or 3DS has to be handled on client side with separate implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with 3DS, however, there is documentation on the Google Pay developer site that talks about SCA: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/sca

> ### Handle the response object
>
> Merchants receive one of the following:
>
> - An authenticated payload that can be processed without any further step-up or challenge.
> - A PAN that requires 3D Secure 2.0 through a solution provided in-house or through payment service provider partners (PSP)
>
> Most of our PSP offer the ability to apply appropriate instrument risk checks and step-up transactions. Where applicable, this includes 3D Secure for Google Pay PAN PAN_ONLY transactions.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this documentation, but it is still unclear, "in-house" actual meaning and is it possible that payment going to be suspended only because we need to have our own 3DS implementation

Comment: I think that in this instance _in-house_ refers to your own 3DS implementation **if** your payment service provider doesn't handle this for you. Which PSP are you? This document suggests that most supported PSPs can handle 3DS for you.